# what is the practical purpose of the Observable.never() function?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

Rxjava has a method Observable.never(), that creates an empty observable, that never completes and never emits anything.

What is the purpose of that specific observable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main purpose is to prevent completing a stream or provide non-emitting Observable to operators that otherwise react to signals of secondary sources (for example, window, takeUntil). In addition, it is great for testing timeout with sequences.